# Method Save in gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-gin

My code looks like this,
If I want to save user, I write this

```
    admin := models.Admin{
        Fullname:       body.Fullname,
        Email:          body.Email,
        PasswordHashed: hashedPassword,
    }
    db.DB().Save(&admin)
```

Instead of calling db in my handles, I want to just use like `admin.Save()` and I wrote code like this

```
    type Admin struct {
      ID             uint64 `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key;unique;AUTO_INCREMENT"`
      Fullname       string `json:"fullname" gorm:"type:varchar(50)"`
      Email          string `json:"email" gorm:"type:varchar(100);unique_index"`
      PasswordHashed string `json:"password_hashed" gorm:"type:varchar(60)"`
      CreatedAt   time.Time `json:"created_at" gorm:"column:created_at"`
      UpdatedAt   time.Time `json:"updated_at" gorm:"column:updated_at"`
    }
    func (a *Admin) Save(){
      db.DB().Save(&a)
    }
```

But when I tried to build the code it says errors: import cycle not allowed. I've read some that say, If I already import package B in package A, I can't import package A in B.
How should I solve this problem? or should I just stay with my first code?
Here is my folder structure

My directory tree

```
   ├── controllers
    │   ├── auth.go
    │   └── auth_test.go
    ├── db
    │   └── db.go
    ├── go.mod
    ├── go.sum
    ├── gournal
    ├── helpers
    │   ├── bcrypt.go
    │   └── jwt.go
    ├── main.go
    ├── makefile
    ├── middlewares
    │   └── auth.go
    ├── models
    │   ├── admin.go
    │   ├── journal.go
    │   └── methods.go
    ├── README.md
    ├── routers
    │   ├── auth.go
    │   └── router.go
    └── test
```

Comment: Can you whow what file is importing what?

Comment: i working with files db.go that have func DB() that imported models from models.go

Comment: Are they in the same folder? Please show folder structure and content of related files in the question.

Comment: What is the error message specifically? You say that db.go imports models.go, so does models.go import db.go directly or indirectly?

Comment: *"How should I solve this problem?"* If you want `models` to import `db` you simply need to make sure that `db` does not import `models` (directly or indirectly), there's nothing else to it.